# Android: How to change standard RadioButtonGroup direction

Tags: android, android-layout, radiobuttonlist

If the android:orientation of the group is "vertical" the standard order is top-down. 
I would need bottom-up, the opposite: the first child to be at the bottom, so the others until the last at the top. 
They must stay in the same order as group's childs but showed in the opposite direction. How should I do?
This to make similar layouts for particular portrait and landscape orientations.

Comment: This is defined by the language.

Answer (score 0):

Change orientation to Vertical or horizontal according to your need

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/commuteby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line0" >
```

Comment: What I asked is different, I know how to change orientation but the order is always top-down for vertical orientation and left-right when it's horizontally oriented. I search for a way to do the opposite, bottom-up and left-right